# slide and fade animation together in flexslider

Tags: jquery, slideshow, flexslider

I need Animation: slide and Animation: Fade together in Flexslider, i have following function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.flexslider').length > 0){
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
           animation: "fade",
           controlNav: true,              
           directionNav: true,
           start: function(slider){
               $('body').removeClass('loading');
           }
        });
    }
```

How to merge the fade animation effect and slide animation effect at the same time.

Comment: your example is missing the close for `ready()`, if this is a transcription error please update.

Comment: You can set animation: "slide" and then you need to add custom behaviour for the fade. You can do this for example, by the same timer it takes to change slide and also the next/previous buttons..

Comment: HOw to add the custome behaviour can you please how me by an example. This will be really helpful if you show me by an example.

Comment: @doublesharp there is no error in the ready() in my local files, it must be just mistake while i copy from the local files can you please help me how to add the custom behaviour for the fade animation if i put the animation: "slide" ???